# Why is the Google Cloud Python library adding redundant logging?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

During `from google.cloud import pubsub_v1`, the Google library adds a `StreamHandler` to the root logger.

This means that with my own logger, each line appears twice.

Setting the `handlers=[]` on the root logger resolves this, but then various libraries including the  Google libraries do not log at all, and I do want their logs.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
import sys

def __configure() -> logging.Logger:
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logger1 = logging.getLogger("the_logger")
    logger1.addHandler(__info_handler())
    logger1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger1


def __info_handler():
    info_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    info_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    return info_handler


the_logger= __configure()


the_logger.info("Hello World 1")
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
the_logger.info("Hello World 2 ")
```

Here is what it prints. Note the duplication.

```
2018-11-21 15:02:26;INFO;Hello World 1
INFO:the_logger:Hello World 2 
2018-11-21 15:02:27;INFO;Hello World 2
```

Comment: How are you creating your logger? Possible you're using the default configuration and then adding an additional handler on top.

Comment: I am creating it with the ordinary constructor  logging.getLogger("thelogger").

You say "using the default configuration" -- how do I avoid that?

Comment: You're almost definitely adding multiple handlers. Running `import logging; logger=logging.getLogger('thelogger'); logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler()); logger.setLevel(logging.INFO); logger.warning('hi')` returns `hi`. If you run that same command twice, the second invocation will print hi to the console twice. The order in which a logger is created matters so it's hard to say exactly why you're getting what you're getting without you showing what you're doing.

Comment: In the line  after the double-logging thelogger.info("xxx), I tried  print(thelogger.handlers). It shows         
"[<StreamHandler <stdout> (INFO)>]" -- in other words, only  one Handler.

But note -- this occurs under Flask [edited main body]. When I run, e.g. a unittest, I don't get this  doubling

Comment: I narrowed this down to a Google library. See body. But I still don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: Edited text to reflect what I learned

Comment: I added code for a minimal reproduction scenario.

Comment: I tried running your sample code both as a script file and from a command prompt and it returned `2018-11-23 16:57:23;INFO;Hello World 1\n2018-11-23 16:57:23;INFO;Hello World 2` without duplication. I think something else is going on with your machine or code that's not included in the sample code.